# Laravel 4 (Eloquent) does not recognize where('date','<','NOW()') - ignores it completely

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have mysql table "announcements" has posts, also has column `publish_date` which is DateTime

When I build my query like this:

```
$announcements = Announcement::where('status',1)
                    ->where('publish_date', '<','NOW()')
                    ->orderBy('publish_date', 'DESC')
                    ->paginate(9);
```

The query log shows:

```
select * from `announcements` 
where `status` = 1 and `publish_date` < NOW() 
order by `publish_date` desc 
limit 9 
offset 0
```

However, this is my dd($announcements->toArray());
(dont have rep power to post images, https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P0nI.png )

If you see the first result has publish_date for August 14, 2014 (Today is 12th)

HOWEVER....

When i RUN IDENTICAL query on the same database in MySQL:
(no rep, no images, sorry:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjEDn.png

this is driving me insane

I have tried various combination of single and double quotes in where statements. I have removed pagination, I have removed status, orderby, same result. Even basic insanity-check: cleared cache. No luck

Am I not writing where statement correctly??

---

THE ONLY HACKJOB solution that works is this:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

.....

```
->where('publish_date', '<', $now)
```

While this works, this is not a legitimate solution from query standpoint. There are other examples where I need to do MySQL date manipulation and if I cannot use NOW(), for example, it will become difficult to resolve it with PHP alternatives.

I'd rather use native NOW() rather than pass date to query. Thank you guys

Comment: try it with sysdate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent accepts Carbon dates for this purpose:

```
$announcements = Announcement::where('status',1)
                ->where('publish_date', '<',Carbon::now())
                ->orderBy('publish_date', 'DESC')
                ->paginate(9);
```

Otherwise you would probaly use:

```
$announcements = Announcement::where('status',1)
                ->where('publish_date', '<',DB::raw('NOW()'))
                ->orderBy('publish_date', 'DESC')
                ->paginate(9);
```

Comment: Dennis, thank you this worked. The Carbon solution is perfect! IT worked!